# React JS 15.0 - Reducers not working at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, xmlhttprequest

I am working at a reactjs app created by someone else, it's a 2016 React js app based on react-redux. It is using React 15.0 with the following config:

```
"react": "^15.0.0",
"react-ace": "^3.4.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.29.4",
"react-chartjs": "^0.7.3",
"react-datepicker": "^0.27.0",
"react-dom": "^15.0.0",
"react-quill": "https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill.git",
"react-redux": "^4.0.0",
"react-redux-toastr": "^3.1.0",
"react-router": "^2.2.0",
"react-router-bootstrap": "^0.22.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-scroll": "^0.2.0",
"react-scroll": "^1.0.15",
"react-select": "^1.0.0-beta13",
"react-stripe-checkout": "^1.8.0",
"redux": "^3.0.0",
"redux-actions": "^0.9.1",
"redux-form": "^5.1.4",
"redux-thunk": "^2.0.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.1",
```

I have issues with the API calls,
I'm using a custom http.js file which makes a promise based on a XHR call. This works well and returns a JSON:

```
function request (path, method, data = undefined) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

   ...

     let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
     xhr.open(method, `//${__DEV__ ? 'localhost:3000' : 'mywebsite.com'}/${path}`, true)
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
     xhr.send(data ? JSON.stringify(data) : data)

   ...

    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    resolve(response)

   ...
   })
}
```

I call the function like:

```
get: (path) => {
    return request(path, 'GET')
  },

Http.get('api/users')
        .then((response) => {
          users= response.resources
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn('Unable to get users:', error)
        })
```

I get the error saying that users is undefined, since response contains the JSON instead of an oject with the key "resources". I'm not a react js developer, but I see that in most of the cases, there is a constructor that defines the structure, but in my case there's no constructor.

I have a custom Reducer for users:

```
// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
export default handleActions({
  [SET_USERS_DATA]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    resources: { data: action.payload, loading: state.resources.loading }
  }),
```

I guess that this is now working well, how can I ensure the fact that the reducer will work well? How can I debug it?

Comment: What do you want to do here: `.then((response) => { users= response.resources` unless users is some global variable you are changing this would cause your error?

Comment: Basically I don't get the users, I get a list of values that is used when the website is loaded. This call is made each time when the website is loaded. But I don't understand who this worked before, because it has no sense to me. Also, in my component, I have the variable defined as: let users = [] and the data from users is used in other calls.

Comment: @Pascut you can use [redux extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am currently downloading it. I'm afraid that redux is not working well, but I wasn't able to debug well using console logs. I will try with the redux devtool.